# How to add your emoticons from emodji_pack to telegram bot in Python?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I create a bot in python using TeleBot. I ran into a problem that you need to use your emoticons, or rather, that the bot sends them in a message.

I created a set of emoticons through @stickers, if you stupidly copy it from tg and paste it into the code, then the replacement smiley is stupidly shown **which is not surprising**.

Is there any option to explain to the bot, through a link to the pack or with the help of a tambourine, that it is necessary to use them? I looked at the Telebot documentation, but did not find the answer. Or is there such a function in other options, such as aiogram or others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's because you need to use the **sticker ID** in order to send custom stickers.

Here's an example to get the sticker ID:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR_TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def handle_sticker(message):
    sticker_file_id = message.sticker.file_id
    print('Sticker ID:', sticker_file_id)

bot.polling()
```

Once you get the Sticker ID, you can use it to send the custom sticker:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR_TOKEN')

sticker_id = 'STICKER_ID'

@bot.message_handler(commands=['send_sticker'])
def send_sticker(message):
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sticker_id)

bot.polling()
```

I hope it was helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to add not a sticker, but an emoji emoticon. I have a link to the created collection, I'm trying to figure out if I can somehow add this collection by reference so that the telegram understands that it is necessary to use a specific emoticon not as usual, but use a replacement from the created collection.